GScript: DriveApp.searchFiles - Parameter for filetype
How do I have to extend the search parameter if I also have to search for GSheet files only?
function myDeleteSharingPublicLinks() {
  var MyAccount = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var myCounter = 0;
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"' + MyAccount  + '" in owners');

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
  }
}


Try driveApp.getFilesByType(mimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS) mimeType Link

Try
function myDeleteSharingPublicLinks() {
  var MyAccount = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var myCounter = 0;
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"' + MyAccount  + '" in owners and mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"');

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
  }
}

You can find the file-specific query terms listed in the Search query terms and operators documentation.
You can find the list of MIME-types in the Google Workspace and Google Drive supported MIME types documentation

While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

@TheMaster I've updated the answer with links to the source documentation.

Many many thanks it works perfect.
It's a pity that Google's documentation describes all the commands but provides very few examples - because these are exactly what I learn best.

Happy to help! Don't forget to mark answered and drop a comment if you need help with any more syntax for the query. I also rely on examples to decompose to learn. There's a decent list of examples here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files#examples
